# Add up values of same key in nested dictionary where keys are elements of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

```
mylist = ['01', '02']
d = {'01': {'age':19, 'answ1':3, 'answ2':7, 'answ3':2},
     '02': {'age':52, 'answ1':8, 'answ2':1, 'answ3':10},
     '03': {'age':32, 'answ1':28, 'answ2':3, 'answ3':15}}
```

It should print the sum of two `dict`s which have the keys `'01'` and `'02'`.

Output should be `{'age':71, 'answ1':11, 'answ2':8, 'answ3':12}`.

I know that it can be done by nested `for` loops but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

Create and empty dictionary initialized to zero. Python can go iterate the items of a list, so it becomes an indexing problem.

```
mylist = ['01', '02']
d = {'01': {'age':19, 'answ1':3, 'answ2':7, 'answ3':2}, '02': {'age':52, 'answ1':8, 'answ2':1, 'answ3':10}, '03': {'age':32, 'answ1':28, 'answ2':3, 'answ3':15}}
sum_dic ={'age':0, 'answ1':0, 'answ2':0, 'answ3':0}
for item in mylist:
    sum_dic['age'] += d[item]['age']
    sum_dic['answ1'] += d[item]['answ1']
    sum_dic['answ2'] += d[item]['answ2']
    sum_dic['answ3'] += d[item]['answ3']
print(sum_dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> totals = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x in (d[k] for k in mylist):
...     for k, v in x.items():
...         totals[k] += v
... 
>>> dict(totals)
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this in one line of code with the help of `functools.reduce`, `collections.Counter` and `operator.(add, itemgetter)` -

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, itemgetter

dict(reduce(add, map(Counter, itemgetter(*mylist)(d))))

#OR 

dict(reduce(add, (Counter(d[i]) for i in mylist)))
```

```
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

---

#### Explanation

Read more about the second part [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sum-list-of-dictionaries-with-same-key/).

- The itemgetter fetches the values in `d` with keys matching the `mylist`. Feel free to change that to a generator.
- A quick example showcases the above code's essence. You can add two Counter dictionaries with a `+` or `operator.add` as shown below -

```
Counter({'a':1,'b':3}) + Counter({'a':4,'b':1})
```

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a dictionary comprehension:

```
mylist = ['01', '02']
d = {'01': {'age':19, 'answ1':3, 'answ2':7, 'answ3':2},
     '02': {'age':52, 'answ1':8, 'answ2':1, 'answ3':10},
     '03': {'age':32, 'answ1':28, 'answ2':3, 'answ3':15}}

r = { k:sum(d[dk][k] for dk in mylist) for k in d[mylist[0]] }

print(r)
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

You can also do it using an iterator in an update call on an existing dictionary:

```
r = dict()
r.update( (k,r.get(k,0)+n) for dk in mylist for k,n in d[dk].items())
```